# Here Maps API getroute linkAttributes Not Returning dynamicSpeedInfo?

Tags: here-api

I am new to Here Maps API, I have just registered for an Evaluation Plan of the platform.

Regarding the [getRoute API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-get-route.html)

linkAttributes
Define which attributes are included in the response as part of the data representation of the route links.

linkAttributes=shape,speedLimit,dynamicSpeedInfo

I am getting a response but no speedLimit,dynamicSpeedInfo information.
Is this a problem with the my Licence? or am I passing the linkAttributes wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the exact url  ?

Answer (score 0):

The SpeedLimit in getLinkInfo has an access restriction in the evaluation plan.

See: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html#link-info

> Note: All link info attributes are subject to additional licensing. We
>   reserve the right to require authorization on API level for all or
>   individual attributes with future releases. Currently, only the
>   SpeedLimit attribute requires authorization and the attribute is not
>   included in LinkInfo if the client application is not authorized to
>   receive this information.

To use it, you need to get in contact with HERE Sales, but the anyway preferred way to get speed limits is most probably the Platform Data Extension:
https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/quick-start.html